# Difference between `dhall format` and `dhall lint`

Tags: dhall

Playing with `dhall` for the first time I saw that it supports these two options:

```
  ./dhall --help
  ...
  lint                     Improve Dhall code
  format                   Formatter for the Dhall language
```

What's the difference between the two? From running them on my sample project it appears they to the same thing. I'd have expected the linter to go further than formatting in some ways (e.g. recommending "idiomatic" dhall) but couldn't find any info on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The improvements `dhall lint` does (at the time of this writing) are listed [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dhall-1.20.1/docs/Dhall-Lint.html#g:1) and currently consist of:

- removing unused `let` bindings
- consolidating nested `let` bindings to use a multiple-`let` binding
- switching legacy `List`-like `Optional` literals to use `Some` / `None` instead
- removing the `constructors` keyword

Generally, you should expect the `dhall lint` improvements to fall into one of two categories:

- Non-controversial improvements to the code

  ... such as the first improvement to remove unused `let` bindings
- Automatic code migrations to help users stay current with newer language features

  ... such as the last three improvements

Comment: Thanks! The hackage link could be just a little more discoverable from the dhall-lang website, it has great info ;-)

Comment: @JohannesRudolph: I added this to the FAQ: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQ)#how-does-dhall-lint-differ-from-dhall-format

Comment: The FAQ has now moved to: https://docs.dhall-lang.org/howtos/FAQ.html#how-does-dhall-lint-differ-from-dhall-format